# React form useState object doesn't work as I want

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a problem with a React app. I have a form with two inputs, and when I submit the form with empty inputs, it should render an error message in each of them. The problem is that it doesn't show for the first input. How can I fix it to display an error in each of those? The implementation is in `useForm.js`.

FormUI image:
[image: FormUI image]

My code:

`Form.js`

```
const Form = () => {
  
const formLogin = () => {
  console.log("Callback function when form is submitted!");
  console.log("Form Values ", values);
}

const {handleChange, values, errors, handleSubmit} = useForm(formLogin);


  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="govgr-form-group gap-bottom">
          <label className="govgr-label govgr-!-font-weight-bold" htmlFor="code">Code*</label>
          {errors.code && <p className="govgr-error-message"><span className="govgr-visually-hidden">Λάθος:</span>{errors.code}</p>}
          <input className={`govgr-input govgr-!-width-three-quarter ${errors.code ? 'govgr-error-input' : ''}`} id="code" name="code" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>

        <fieldset>
          <div className="govgr-form-group">
            <label className="govgr-label govgr-!-font-weight-bold" htmlFor="first">Name*</label>
            {errors.first && <p className="govgr-error-message"><span className="govgr-visually-hidden">Λάθος:</span>{errors.first}</p>}
            <input className={`govgr-input govgr-!-width-three-quarter ${errors.first ? 'govgr-error-input' : ''}`} id="first" name="first" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          </div>

         
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" className="govgr-btn govgr-btn-primary btn-center">Save</button>

      </form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

`useForm.js`:

```
const useForm = (callback) => {
  
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validate = (event, name, value) => {
    
    event.persist();

    switch (name) {
      case "code":
        if (value.trim() === "" || value.trim() === null) {
          setErrors({
            ...errors,
            code: "Code is required",
          });
        } else {
          let newObj = omit(errors, "code");
          setErrors(newObj);
        }
        break;

      case "first":
        if (value.trim() === "" || value.trim() === null) {
          setErrors({
            ...errors,
            first: "Name is required",
          });
        } else {
          let newObj = omit(errors, "first");
          setErrors(newObj);
        }
        break;

        

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();

    let name = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;

    validate(event, name, val);

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: val,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();

    if (
      Object.keys(errors).length === 0 &&
      Object.keys(values).length !== 0 &&
      values.code &&
      values.first 
    ) {
      callback();
    } else {
      if (!values.code) {
        setErrors({
          ...errors,
          code: "Code is required.",
        });
      }
      if (!values.first) {
        setErrors({
          ...errors,
          first: "Name is required.",
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    values,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

Comment: You don't need `event.persist()` in this code. That's only for async handlers. Also, you have duplicated the validation code. Neither of those things is causing your error, but you should take care of them anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't use `errors` in the `setErrors` call. You should use this construct instead: `setErrors(e => ({...e, code: "Code is required"}))`. Same things applies when trying to remove the error: use `setErrors(e => e.filter(e.hasOwnProperty('code'))`, or something like that.

Comment: I don't think you can use a switch statement here, by default a switch statement returns ONE of MANY options. Hence you will only ever return a single error you can read more here -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp I also think this code is WAY over complicated for what you're trying to achieve, maybe a re-write is in order.

Comment: @snazzyy - the validate/switch is being called from the onchange event, which is only called for a change in a single field so it's correct. I agree that this code is too complicated though.

Comment: You're correct @SoftwareEngineer

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Thanks for your answer, it worked. I used this construct of updating errors in my handleSubmit function. Should i use it in handleChange function in switch statement too? I know it is complicated, i want to validate using onChange so when the user types in input, error messages appear and dissapear. But, i want to validate onSubmit too, so in case he submit without typing in inputs error messages appear in the required inputs.

Comment: Yeah, you should just call the validate routine. If you remove `event.persist()` then you don't need the event param and you can then call it twice from submit (once for each field). You'll need validate to return a boolean (true if valid, else false) so that you can decide on submitting the form or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by having only a single validation routine. You can fix the error you mention, having only a single error at a time, by using the current state as passed into `setState` by the framework. The construct for this is

```js
setState(e => /* whatever you want to return relative to e */);
```

Ultimately, the error you're seeing is because the component, and its code, is rerendered after every change of state (but they are batched for performance reasons), so your code is only seeing an older version of the state when you access it directly. If you want the actual current state when changing it, it's always best to have the framework pass it directly to the change-state function. If you always follow this pattern, you will rarely have any problems with the react state model.

The hard problem however isn't any of this. The hard problem is the way you're removing errors. First, from a UI perspective, it's a little inconsistent to only show a field as an error when it is edited, because the form is erroneous when it's first shown. But, ignoring that, the underlying technical problem is removing a property from an object. Normally we would use arrays rather than objects when we need to do this, or we would use underscore's `omit` function. I see in your code you call a function called `omit`, but you don't have an explanation as to what that is. In your case though, this can be easily solved by never removing the property. Instead, have each as an object with a valid flag. This would allow you to remove the switch statement completely.

You could go further and roll the value in there too, making a complete single state for each field, but I won't demonstrate that here.

I haven't tested this, so there may be a typo or two lurking in here.

```js
const useForm = (callback) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({code: '', first: ''});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({first: {message: "Name is required", valid: true}, code: {message: "Code is required", valid: true}});

  const isEmpty = val => val.trim() === "" || val.trim() === null);

  const validate = (name, val) => {
    setErrors(e => ({...e, [name]: {...e[name], valid: isEmpty(val)}}))
    return errors[name].valid;
  };
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;
    setValues({...values, [name]: val});
    validate(name, val);
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();

    const valid = validate('code', values.code) && validate('first', values.first);

    if ( valid ) {
      callback();
    } 
  };

  return {
    values,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

And, you'd have to change your HTML template slightly:

```html
{!errors.first.valid && <p className="govgr-error-message"><span className="govgr-visually-hidden">Λάθος:</span>{errors.first.message}</p>}
```

I realise that this new `validate` function is a huge departure from what you had, but based on your own code I think you can handle it. Basically, it's just using destructuring and variable property accessors. This looks like its well within your capabilities to understand, but feel free to ask more questions if any of it is confusing or doesn't actually work :)